# Rewriting single post url; add_rewrite_rule problem?

Tags: permalinks, customization, rewrite-rules

I have to customize single post permalink (the structure of the permalink) if posts have a certain value in a certain custom fields.

I use the filter `post_link` to change permalink when needed, and this works greatly (I mean, in front-end permalink are different when they should).

First question: in your opinion I have to use other filters to cover all cases of single post permalink customization?

Then I have added specific rule using [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to interpret this new kind of structure, and here I face the problem.

As this permalink structure has the ID (with 0 at the beginning in order to reach 6 digit, ex. 008467) at the end, I notice that Wordpress redirects to a new url with this number - cast to an integer - repeated, for example:

from

```
/CATEGORYNAME/2013/04/22/POSTSLUG/008467/
```

to

```
/CATEGORYNAME/2013/04/22/POSTSLUG/008467/8467/
```

Do not worry about the structure before POSTSLUG, in fact the important thing is that if I remove the POSTID from the structure (008647) all works fine! For example, the following works:

```
/CATEGORYNAME/2013/04/22/POSTSLUG/
```

How is it possible?! It seems that Wordpress thinks that number is something different, like pagination or something similar.

This is the rule I have added (the regexp is correct, I have tried it with an online tester):

```
add_rewrite_rule(  
    '(.+?)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.?.+?)/([0-9]{6})(/[0-9]+)?/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=$matches[5]&page=$matches[7]',
    'top');
```

Comment: It's hard to diagnose this without seeing all of your code, but I'm guessing the issue is the fact that you're forcing the post id to be 6 digits. Is there any reason why you can't change that to ditch the leading zeros?